# pgfplots: plot smaller range of table and still use enlargelimits=true

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplots to plot two simple (x,y)-plots of the same data from a table file. The first plot shows all of the data points and in the second plot I want to zoom in on some specific range of the data. However when I use `xmin` and `xmax` to restrict the range the first and last point gets placed on the axis box. I want to add a little space between the axes and the points so I try to set `enlargelimits=true` but then points outside the range gets shown and are not clipped away as I thought they would be.

Is there a way to do this without having to copy the desired data-point into a new table?

Heres an example of what I try to do: I have the data file `plotdata.dat`:

```
# plotdata.dat
x   y
0   0
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
6   36
7   49
8   64
9   81
10  100
11  121
12  144
```

And my latex document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=11, enlargelimits=true]
\addplot[only marks] table[x index=0, y index=1] {plotdata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then even though `xmin=1` the plot shows also the `x=0` point. I don't want to just set the axis limits so that only the range is shown but instead ignore points outside the range...

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also search for the `enlargelimits` command in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) for different options regarding the axis scales etc.

Comment: Thanks! I've already looked through the manual and tried different options but they don't seem to help me.

I'll edit my question to show an example...

Answer (score 7):

The displayed range is independent of the set of data points which are being displayed.

In other words: even if you choose `xmin` and `xmax` in a way which hides all data points, pgfplots will still draw *every* data point.

If you want to select/discard subsets of your data points, you should study the filtering mechanisms, in particular: the `restrict x to domain=1:9999` key with appropriate values. Filtering means to drop single coordinates. The `unbounded coords=discard|jump` key controls how pgfplots should react (either as if it never saw the discarded points at all or by introducing jumps).

Comment: Is there also a ´restrict y to domain´ key?

Comment: Yes. In fact, there are a couple of variants, including `restrict expr to domain` in which you provide a custom expression. There are also variants with an asterisk, ie `restrict y to domain*` in which points outside of the domain will be clipped to the next matching boundary. See the manual for details.